# Why can React value be used befor it's defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code, why is initialTasks  used before it's defined?

```js
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import AddTask from './AddTask.js';
import TaskList from './TaskList.js';

export default function TaskApp() {
  const [tasks, dispatch] = useReducer(tasksReducer, initialTasks);

  function handleAddTask(text) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'added',
      id: nextId++,
      text: text,
    });
  }

  function handleChangeTask(task) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'changed',
      task: task,
    });
  }

  function handleDeleteTask(taskId) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'deleted',
      id: taskId,
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>布拉格的行程安排</h1>
      <AddTask onAddTask={handleAddTask} />
      <TaskList
        tasks={tasks}
        onChangeTask={handleChangeTask}
        onDeleteTask={handleDeleteTask}
      />
    </>
  );
}

function tasksReducer(tasks, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'added': {
      return [
        ...tasks,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          done: false,
        },
      ];
    }
    case 'changed': {
      return tasks.map((t) => {
        if (t.id === action.task.id) {
          return action.task;
        } else {
          return t;
        }
      });
    }
    case 'deleted': {
      return tasks.filter((t) => t.id !== action.id);
    }
    default: {
      throw Error('未知 action: ' + action.type);
    }
  }
}

let nextId = 3;
const initialTasks = [
  {id: 0, text: '参观卡夫卡博物馆', done: true},
  {id: 1, text: '看木偶戏', done: false},
  {id: 2, text: '打卡列侬墙', done: false}
];
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

The constant 'initialTasks' is defined towards the end of the file, but it's not being defined after its use. It's use in 'useReducer' doesn't occur until the function (TaskApp) is called.

In other words, reading the code from top to bottom, first we define a function (TaskApp), then afterwards we define some variables (nextId and initialTasks). The contents of the function isn't run until that function is called, which won't happen right away as its defined.

Comment: This is very close and correct as far as it goes, but the other part of why it works is declaration hoisting: the variable must exist in the outer scope or you would get a ReferenceError in strict mode. See the linked duplicate.